# How to use "distanceTo", "advancedBy" to handle String in Xcode7 beta6

Tags: xcode, string, swift

I have an extension on String, it works fine on Xcode7 beta5.
However, I upgraded to beta 6 yesterday. It seems Swift syntax has some changes. There are some errors while compiling my code.

[image]

==================================================

Yes. it shows which methods I should use and also finds some information on apple website. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS81APIDiffs/modules/Swift.html

When I change the "distance" => "distanceTo". I got the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'distance to'". Does anyone know how to use "distanceTo", "advancedBy" exactly ?? 
[image]

Comment: What part of the error messages are you finding confusing? They tell you exactly what new method to use.

Comment: Post the code, not the screen shot

Comment: I update my question title to make my question more clearly. I should ask how to distanceTo & advancedBy in Xcode7 beta6.

Answer (score 7):

What's happened is that the global functions `distance` and `advance` have been replaced by *instance methods* `distanceTo` and `advancedBy`.

Comment: What class are `distanceTo` and `advancedBy` methods of?  An example would be helpful, especially an example that rearranges the syntax shown by the OP.

Comment: @Tony they are instance methods of whatever you were previously using as the first parameter when they were global functions. :)

Answer (score 4):

OK, I figure out how to use these.

[image]

Comment: Stop posting screen shots of code. Just stop it. Post _code_.