# How to use substringFromIndex in Playground?

Tags: xcode, swift2

In the Swift playground (Xcode 7), why does the following

```
var someString = "my four word string"
someString.substringFromIndex(advance(someString.startIndex, 5))
```

produce this error:

> 'advance' is unavailable: call the 'advanceBy(n)' on the index

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use "distanceTo", "advancedBy" to handle String in Xcode7 beta6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216817/how-to-use-distanceto-advancedby-to-handle-string-in-xcode7-beta6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 2 you should use `[String].advanceBy([Int])` instead of `advance([String], [Int])`

```
var someString = "my four word string"
someString.substringFromIndex(someString.startIndex.advancedBy(5))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is code for sub String in Swift 2.0:

```
var givenString = "some string"
let subString = givenString[someString.startIndex.advancedBy(4)]  //some
```